# Visualization issue while using Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet, r-mapview

I have two data frame as below:

```
PickUP <- data.frame(pickuplong = c(-73.93909 ,-73.94189 ,-73.93754,-73.91638,-73.92792 ,-73.88634), pickuplat =c(40.84408,40.83841,40.85311,40.84966,40.86284,40.85628)) 

Dropoff <- data.frame(pickuplong = c(-73.93351 ,-73.93909 ,-73.93909 ,-73.80747,-73.95722,-73.91880), pickuplat =c(40.76621,40.84408,40.85311,40.69951,40.68877,40.75917), Droplong =c(-73.91300,-73.96259 ,-73.94870,-73.93860,-73.93633, -73.90690), Droplat =c(40.77777,40.77488 ,40.78493,40.84463,40.75977,40.77013))
```

I  try to find the pickup coordinations (longtitude and latitude) in the **pickup data frame** which are repeated in **dropoff dataframe**. I have the below code but I got the error on this:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)
a <- semi_join(Dropoff , PickUP , by = c("pickuplong","pickuplat"))
a$ID <- 1:nrow(a) 
Dropoff_p <- a[, c("ID", "Pickup_longitude", "Pickup_latitude")]
Dropoff_d <- a[, c("ID", "Dropoff_longitude", "Dropoff_latitude")]
coordinates(Dropoff_p) <- ~Pickup_longitude + Pickup_latitude
coordinates(Dropoff_d) <- ~Dropoff_longitude + Dropoff_latitude
proj4string(Dropoff_p) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
proj4string(Dropoff_d) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
map_p <- mapview(Dropoff_p, color = "red")
map_d <- mapview(Dropoff_d, color = "blue")
map_p + map_d
```

My error is:

> Error in $<-.data.frame (*tmp*, "ID", value = c(1L, 0L)) :
>       replacement has 2 rows, data has 0 Error during wrapup: cannot open the 
>       connection

Answer (score 0):

When subsetting the data frame, you have to use the same column names. I changed the column name in the `Dropoff_p`, `Dropoff_d`, `coordinates(Dropoff_p)`, and `proj4string(Dropoff_d)`, and then your script works.

In addition, the `mapview` package just has a new update. If you want, you can update your `mapview` to version `2.0.1`. You can also add `col.regions = "red"` and `col.regions = "blue"` because it seems like under the new version the `color` argument will only change the outline of a point. To change the fill color, use `col.regions`.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)

a <- semi_join(Dropoff , PickUP , by = c("pickuplong","pickuplat"))
a$ID <- 1:nrow(a) 
Dropoff_p <- a[, c("ID", "pickuplong", "pickuplat")]
Dropoff_d <- a[, c("ID", "Droplong", "Droplat")]
coordinates(Dropoff_p) <- ~pickuplong + pickuplat
coordinates(Dropoff_d) <- ~Droplong + Droplat
proj4string(Dropoff_p) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
proj4string(Dropoff_d) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
map_p <- mapview(Dropoff_p, color = "red", col.regions = "red")
map_d <- mapview(Dropoff_d, color = "blue", col.regions = "blue")
map_p + map_d
```

Comment: I got error in the second line where a$ID <- 1:nrow(a)

Comment: do you know how can I change the circle icons on the map to other shapes like rectangular. Thanks

Comment: @Behzad I don't know if there is an easy way to change the symbol from circle to rectangular. Please see the documentation of `mapview` https://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/mapview/introduction.html or `leaflet` for more information. By the way, if my solutions can at least solve your original questions. Please accept them as answers.